# Semaphore that can decrease its current count by N (N>=1)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-synchronization

I am implementing a flow control component that limits maximum requests can be sent. Every worker thread can send either a single request or a batch of requests, but at any time the total amount of pending requests should not exceed a maximum number.

I initially want to implement with a SemaphoreSlim: 
initialising the semaphore to the maximum request count, then when a worker thread is going to call service, it must acquire enough count of tokens, however I found actually SemaphoreSlim and Semaphore only allow a thread to decrease Semaphore count by 1, in my case I want to decrease the count by the number of requests that work thread carries.

What synchronization primitive should I use here?

Just to clarify, the service supports batch processing, so one thread can send a N requests in one service call, but accordingly it should be able to decrease semaphore's current count by N.

Comment: Why not `Wait` the semaphore for each expected request you're going to make?

Comment: @JonathonChase my service supports batch, so it is one service call. Are you suggesting to call SemaphoreSlim.Wait() multiple times in same thread?

Comment: How shall one thread process multiple requests at the same time? Do you use async/await?

Comment: @ThomasWeller As I mentioned above, my service supports batch processing, so if a worker thread carries a number of requests, it directly calls the service's batch endpoint.

Comment: Yeah, but only for one request at a time. So it acquires the semaphore for 1 token, and processes 1 request. It can keep that 1 token and process another 1 request. And repeat that as long as it wants to. Anything wrong with that?

Comment: @ThomasWeller you didn't get me, (1) service accepts batch, no need to call service many times; (2) total amount of requests is still bounded.

Comment: Maybe I got it. I think you're explaining it wrong. You don't want to limit the number of requests that clients can send, you want to limit the amount of work on the server. Is that about right? Maybe you want to achieve that by limiting the number of client requests, but that's an XY-problem.

Comment: @ThomasWeller let me explain it with example.(1) service accepts batch, if a thread carries 10 requests, it can send these 10 requests to service in one HTTP call, no need to call service 10 times; (2) service side requires the total amount of incoming requests is bounded, let's say the maximum requests count is 30, so on client it could be: there are 30 threads and each thread sends 1 requests, or there is only 1 thread sends 30 requests, if there are other threads want to send requests, they must wait.

Comment: Thank you guys for the suggestion, I ended up with an approximate solution. I created a semaphore with initial count = max requests / max batch size.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a custom `SemaphoreManyFifo` class that offers the methods `Wait(int acquireCount)` method and `Release(int releaseCount)`. Its behavior is strictly FIFO. It has a quite decent performance (~500,000 operations per second on 8 threads in my PC).

```
public class SemaphoreManyFifo : IDisposable
{
    private readonly object _locker = new object();
    private readonly Queue<(ManualResetEventSlim, int AcquireCount)> _queue;
    private readonly ThreadLocal<ManualResetEventSlim> _pool;
    private readonly int _maxCount;
    private int _currentCount;

    public int CurrentCount => Volatile.Read(ref _currentCount);

    public SemaphoreManyFifo(int initialCount, int maxCount)
    {
        // Proper arguments validation omitted
        Debug.Assert(initialCount >= 0);
        Debug.Assert(maxCount > 0 && maxCount >= initialCount);
        _queue = new Queue<(ManualResetEventSlim, int)>();
        _pool = new ThreadLocal<ManualResetEventSlim>(
            () => new ManualResetEventSlim(false), trackAllValues: true);
        _currentCount = initialCount;
        _maxCount = maxCount;
    }
    public SemaphoreManyFifo(int initialCount) : this(initialCount, Int32.MaxValue) { }

    public void Wait(int acquireCount)
    {
        Debug.Assert(acquireCount > 0 && acquireCount <= _maxCount);
        ManualResetEventSlim gate;
        lock (_locker)
        {
            Debug.Assert(_currentCount >= 0 && _currentCount <= _maxCount);
            if (acquireCount <= _currentCount && _queue.Count == 0)
            {
                _currentCount -= acquireCount; return; // Fast path
            }
            gate = _pool.Value;
            gate.Reset(); // Important, because the gate is reused
            _queue.Enqueue((gate, acquireCount));
        }
        gate.Wait();
    }

    public void Release(int releaseCount)
    {
        Debug.Assert(releaseCount > 0);
        lock (_locker)
        {
            Debug.Assert(_currentCount >= 0 && _currentCount <= _maxCount);
            if (releaseCount > _maxCount - _currentCount)
                throw new SemaphoreFullException();
            _currentCount += releaseCount;
            while (_queue.Count > 0 && _queue.Peek().AcquireCount <= _currentCount)
            {
                var (gate, acquireCount) = _queue.Dequeue();
                _currentCount -= acquireCount;
                gate.Set();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach (var gate in _pool.Values) gate.Dispose();
        _pool.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Adding support for timeout and cancellation in the above implementation is not trivial. It would require a different (updateable) data structure instead of the `Queue<T>`.

---

The original [`Wait+Pulse`](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Signaling_with_Wait_and_Pulse) implementation can be found in the [1st revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56283762/1) of this answer. It is simple, but it lacks the desirable FIFO behavior.

Comment: That was my first reaction too, but this suffer from starvation : a `Wait` with a large count value can wait forever if a lot of small tasks are entering continuously, never leaving enough space for the larger task to execute.

Comment: @SamuelVidal yes, that's a problem. [Your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56283664/11178549) takes care of it. 

Comment: I wonder if it can be simplified though like using a single locking objet.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you want something like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace Sema
{
    class Program
    {
        // do a little bit of timing magic
        static ManualResetEvent go = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        static void Main()
        {
            // limit the resources
            var s = new SemaphoreSlim(30, 30);

            // start up some threads
            var threads = new List<Thread>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                var start = new ParameterizedThreadStart(dowork);
                Thread t = new Thread(start);
                threads.Add(t);
                t.Start(s);
            }

            go.Set();

            // Wait until all threads finished
            foreach (Thread thread in threads)
            {
                thread.Join();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        private static void dowork(object obj)
        {
            go.WaitOne();
            var s = (SemaphoreSlim) obj;
            var batchsize = 3;

            // acquire tokens
            for (int i = 0; i < batchsize; i++)
            {
                s.Wait();
            }

            // send the request
            Console.WriteLine("Working on a batch of size " + batchsize);
            Thread.Sleep(200);

            s.Release(batchsize);
        }
    }
}
```

However, you'll soon figure out that this causes deadlocks. You'll additionally need some synchronization on the semaphore to guarantee that one thread either gets all of its tokens or none.

```
        var trylater = true;
        while (trylater)
        {
            lock (s)
            {
                if (s.CurrentCount >= batchsize)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < batchsize; i++)
                    {
                        s.Wait();
                    }

                    trylater = false;
                }
            }

            if (trylater)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }
        }
```

Now, that's potentially suffering from starvation. A huge batch (say 29) may never get enough resources while hundreds single requests are made.