# Implementing a Starve method ("Unrelease"/"Hold") for SemaphoreSlim

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, locking, race-condition

I'm using a `SemaphoreSlim` [with a FIFO behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415708/how-to-create-a-fifo-strong-semaphore) and now I want to add to it a `Starve(int amount)` method to remove threads from the pool, sort of the opposite to `Release()`.

If there are any running tasks, they will of course continue until they are done, since for the moment the semaphore is not keeping track of what is actually running and "owes" the semaphore a release call.

The reason is that the user will dynamically control how many processes are allowed at any time for a given semaphore.

The strategy I'm following is:

- if there are threads available, i.e., `CurrentCount > 0`, then call `Await()` on the SemaphoreSlim without releasing back.
- if there are no more threads available, because presumably tasks are running and potentially even queuing, then next time that `Release()` is called ignore it to prevent threads being released (an int variable keeps count)

I have added the code I have so far below. The main issues I'm struggling with are how to ensure thread safety, no deadlocks and no surprising race conditions.

Given that I cannot access the private lock() of the semaphore, I created a new object to at least try and prevent several threads to manipulate the new variables (within the wrapper) at the same time.

However, I fear that other variables like `CurrentCount` which are within the SemaphoreSlim could also change half way through and mess things up... I would expect the lock in the `Release()` method to prevent changes to `CurrentCount`, but maybe I should also apply the lock to the Wait and WaitAsync (which potentially could also change CurrentCount)? That would probably also result in uneccessary locks between two calls to Wait (?)

The call to `semaphore.Wait()` is in this situation any better or worse than `await semaphore.WaitAsync()` ?

Are there any better ways to extend the functionality of a class such as SemaphoreSlim, which contains many private variables that potentially are needed or that would be useful to have access to?

I briefly considered creating a new class which inherits from SemaphoreSlim, or looking at extension methods, maybe using reflection to access the private variables,... but none seem to be obvious or valid.

```
    public class SemaphoreQueue
    {
        private SemaphoreSlim semaphore;
        private ConcurrentQueue<TaskCompletionSource<bool>> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<TaskCompletionSource<bool>>();

        private int releasesToIgnore;
        private object lockObj;
        private const int NO_MAXIMUM = Int32.MaxValue; // cannot access SemaphoreSlim.NO_MAXIMUM
        public SemaphoreQueue(int initialCount) : this(initialCount, NO_MAXIMUM) { }
        public SemaphoreQueue(int initialCount, int maxCount)
        {
            semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount, maxCount);
            lockObj = new object();
            releasesToIgnore = 0;
        }
        public void Starve(int amount)
        {
            lock (lockObj)
            {
                // a maximum of CurrentCount threads can be immediatelly starved by calling Wait without release
                while ((semaphore.CurrentCount > 0) && (amount > 0))
                {
                    semaphore.Wait();
                    amount -= 1;
                }
                // presumably there are still tasks running. The next Releases will be ignored.
                if (amount > 0)
                    releasesToIgnore += amount;
            }
        }
        public int Release()
        {
            return Release(1);
        }
        public int Release(int num)
        {
            lock (lockObj)
            {
                if (releasesToIgnore > num)
                {
                    releasesToIgnore -= num;
                    return semaphore.CurrentCount;
                }
                else
                {
                    int oldReleasesToIgnore = releasesToIgnore;
                    releasesToIgnore = 0;
                    return semaphore.Release(num - oldReleasesToIgnore);
                }
            }
        }
        public void Wait(CancellationToken token)
        {
            WaitAsync(token).Wait();
        }
        public Task WaitAsync(CancellationToken token)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            queue.Enqueue(tcs);
            QueuedAwait(token);
            return tcs.Task;
        }
        public int CurrentCount { get => this.semaphore.CurrentCount; }
        private void QueuedAwait(CancellationToken token)
        {
            semaphore.WaitAsync(token).ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                TaskCompletionSource<bool> popped;
                if (queue.TryDequeue(out popped))
                    popped.SetResult(true);
            });
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            semaphore.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The standard SemaphoreSlim does not have a FIFO behaviour.
Once you have FIFO if you add an exta Wait it would land at the end of the queue, which means, it will not use a count until the Wait is due.
The initial implementation was with a "priority" queue, such that the Wait would effectively skip the queue, but it felt a bit like going against what a queue really means...
So instead, the release is intercepted and not applied until the count is reduced by the required amount.

Comment: Related: [Semaphore that can decrease its current count by N (N>=1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56283112/semaphore-that-can-decrease-its-current-count-by-n-n-1)