# How to dynamically control Parallelism Degree based on object sizes (or some system constraints)?

Tags: c#, algorithm, parallel-processing, constraints, task-parallel-library

Let's **simplify** this scenario. There is a machine with 16 GB RAM, and 4 CPU cores. Given a list of objects with different sizes, e.g. `[3,1,7,9,4,5,2]`, each of the elements surely needs the corresponding amount of RAM based on their size, e.g. "1" will need 1 GB RAM.

What is the best way to process this element lists **in parallel**, without causing `OutOfMemory`, in C#, with Parallelism library (built-in or 3rd party)?

One **naive** strategy could be:

1. First round: choose [3,1,7]. Still have one core left, but if using "9", the program would need 20 GB RAM. So let's for now use 3 cores.
2. Second round: if "3" is finished first, consider "9", but still surpass 16 GB RAM capacity (1+7+9 = 17). So, stop and wait.
3. Third round: if then "7" is finished, the program will move on with "1", "9" and "4".

I'm not an expert on algorithm as well as parallelism. So I can't frame this problem in more specific details... Any help, link, advice is highly appreciated. I believe this problem may have been solved somewhere else, and I don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: The answer depends in part on the degree of fairness you require from your algorithm. For example, with 16GB RAM if something in your list requires all 16GB, is it acceptable for it to go last after every other item is scheduled, or is it important to preserve some semblance of e.g. first in, first out? This is a bin packing problem. Perhaps worth reading up on it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Comment: *Don't* simplify. Right now there's almost no information. What does `process this element lists in parallel` mean? What does the algorithm do? What is the actual problem? How many elements are there? And why can't it reuse memory between elements? Without that the question is meaningless. PLINQ and Parallel.ForEach will partition the data and use one worker task per core *and* adjust the number of workers based on the load. If the algorithm reuses memory (as it should), RAM size shouldn't be a problem. .NET uses Memory and Array pools to avoid allocating new big buffers

Comment: Parallel processing refers to using all cores to process lots of data, not allocating the memory for that data. It's not the *only* way to process lots of data though. If you can treat the problem as a dataflow, ie a pipeline of processing blocks, you can handle an arbitrary number of elements without loading all of them in memory. Parallelism comes from having multiple blocks execute concurrently. It's also possible to have multiple pipelines, each with different constraints, eg using different buffers.

Comment: The specifics *do* matter. You can calculate statistics like sum, count and average, for a 10GB file of data using only a stream and a couple of threads *faster* than if you tried to load everything into memory, if you update a `count` and `sum` variable for each number you read. By the time you read the entire file, you'd have the result. You'd use only as much memory as the stream buffer needs (4KB-8KB). You could improve on that by using one thread to read multiple lines, another to parse the lines and update the variables. And finally, parallelism could come from processing multiple files

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using a specialized `Semaphore` that can have its [`CurrentCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.currentcount) decreased and increased atomically by more than 1, like the one found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56283112/semaphore-that-can-decrease-its-current-count-by-n-n-1) question. You could initialize this mechanism with an `initialCount` equal to the available memory in GBs (16), and `Wait`/`Release` it with the size of each object in GBs (between 1 and 16). This way an object could acquire the semaphore only after waiting for the `CurrentCount` to become equal or larger to its size.

To incorporate this mechanism in a [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) loop, you could create a deferred enumerable that would `Wait` for the semaphore as part of the enumeration, and then feed this throttled enumerable as the source of the parallel loop. One important detail you should take care of is to disable the chunk partitioning that the `Parallel.ForEach` employs by default, by using the [`EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.enumerablepartitioneroptions) configuration, otherwise the `Parallel.ForEach` may enumerate greedily more than one items at a time, interfering with the throttling intentions of this algorithm.

The semaphore should be released inside the body of the parallel loop, in a `finally` block, with the same `releaseCount` as the size of the processed object.

Putting everything together:

```
var items = new[] { 3, 1, 7, 9, 4, 5, 2 };
const int availableMemory = 16; // GB
using var throttler = new SemaphoreManyFifo(availableMemory, availableMemory);
var throttledItems = items
    .Select(item => { throttler.Wait(item); return item; });
var partitioner = Partitioner.Create(throttledItems,
    EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering);
var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
};
Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, parallelOptions, item =>
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} > Processing #{item}");
        Thread.Sleep(item * 1000); // Simulate a CPU-bound operation
    }
    finally
    {
        throttler.Release(item);
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} > Item #{item} completed");
    }
});
```

**Note:** the size of each object should not exceed the `initialCount` of the semaphore, otherwise this algorithm will malfunction. Be aware that the aforementioned [`SemaphoreManyFifo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56283112/semaphore-that-can-decrease-its-current-count-by-n-n-1/56283762#56283762) implementation does not include proper argument validation.